# Compare two array of objects in javascript/angular and return as soon first condition satisfies (any lodash operator)

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash

Say I have two arrays of objects:

```
let ar1 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'abc',
    job: 'dev'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'xyz',
    job: 'qa'
},{
    id: 3,
    name: 'pqr',
    job: 'dev'
  }
];
    
let arr2 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'abc',
    job: 'dev'
},{
    id: 2,
    name: 'zzz',
    job: 'qa'
},{
    id: 3,
    name: 'pqr',
    job: 'dev'
}];
```

I need to compare them so that I get 'true' and exit the comparison without iterating further as the name is different in the second element between two objects.

I tried with the following code:

```
    private compareObjects(obj1, obj2) {
      obj1.forEach((x) => {
         obj2.forEach((y) => {
            if (x.id === y.id) {
            return (!_.isEqual(x, y));
             }
         });
      });
    }
```

Comment: `forEach` is not expected to return a result.

Comment: You can't break out of a `.forEach`, by design, but you _can_ break out of a [for... of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), also by design. You want to use `for...of` in this case. However, if  you want strict comparison, you don't need a double for loop, because arr1.length has to be the same as arr2.length (or they're not equal) and you also know that arr1[i] has to equal arr2[i], so you can use one `let i=0, e=arr1.length; i <e; i++` and save yourself a lot of runtime there, too.

Comment: You should consider using https://lodash.com/docs/#find instead of forEach.  find where there are things different, and at the top level if you find something, return false (for not equal).  Otherwise, return true.

Comment: You're not quite telling us what you're trying to accomplish, what is the point of iterating over the two arrays? Depending on the goal, you could use `Array.prototype.find()`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `reduce`-ing the second array to what's needed for testing the first array: { id : name }.  This is a single pass on the second array.

Then use `find` to test the first array with a single pass that halts on the first mismatch.

```js
let ar1 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'abc',
    job: 'dev'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'xyz',
    job: 'qa'
},{
    id: 3,
    name: 'pqr',
    job: 'dev'
  }
];
    
let arr2 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'abc',
    job: 'dev'
},{
    id: 2,
    name: 'zzz',
    job: 'qa'
},{
    id: 3,
    name: 'pqr',
    job: 'dev'
}];

let index = arr2.reduce((acc, e) => {
  acc[e.id] = e.name
  return acc
}, {})


let firstMismatched = ar1.find(e => index[e.id] !== e.name) 
console.log(firstMismatched)
```